# mybatis PersistenceException Mapper error

Tags: mybatis

I don't know what is wrong.
Something is bad with mapper but everything looks good.

File UserMapper.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mapper namespace="com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.UserMapper">
    <select id="addUser" parameterType="int" resultType="com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.User">
        insert into  * from users where id = #{id}
    </select>
    <select id="getUser" parameterType="int" resultType="com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.User">
        select * from com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.User where id = #{id}
    </select>  
</mapper>
```

I get this Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error building SqlSession.
### The error may exist in UserMapper.xml
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 70; Document root element "mapper", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:23)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:35)
at Main.do1(Main.java:105)
at Main.main(Main.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 70; Document root element "mapper", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
```

Comment: Can you show full mapper file?

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tg2wejt8fmtxkpf/mybatis3.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following doc type. However I find some discrepancy in the code you have copied. Are you sure of INSERT and SELECT statements. I hope its copy mistake

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.UserMapper">

    <select id="addUser" parameterType="int" resultType="com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.User">
        insert into  * from users where id = #{id}
    </select>

    <select id="getUser" parameterType="int" resultType="com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.User">
        select * from com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.User where id = #{id}
    </select>

</mapper>
```